# Submit form if db row empty

Tags: php, database, row

I use this code to display `Submit` form button if `invoice` row is empty. If it's not, then I show the `invoice` row value. The main problem is I can't figure out how to do syntactically-correct change to display other submit button where now row invoice value is.

```
". (empty($row['invoice'])? '<form action="page.php" method="post"><input type="submit" alt="Submit Form" value="Submit" /></form>' :  $row['invoice']) ."
```

I think it should be something like this:

```
". (empty($row['invoice'])? '<form action="page.php" method="post"><input type="submit" alt="Submit Form" value="Submit" /></form>' :  '<form action="page.php" method="post"><input type="submit" alt="Submit Form" value="Submit" /></form>' ."
```

Maybe anyone can help me to work this out?

Comment: remove ". in beginning and ." at end and try.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: it ll be like this
$a = (empty($row['invoice'])? '<form action="page.php" method="post"><input type="submit" alt="Submit Form" value="Submit" /></form>' :  $row['invoice']);

Comment: Niranjan I want to make the second code syntactically-correct, the first one is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

copy the below code, you have missed )

```
(empty($row['invoice']))? '<form action="page.php" method="post"><input type="submit" alt="Submit Form" value="Submit" /></form>' :  '<form action="page.php" method="post"><input type="submit" alt="Submit Form" value="Submit" /></form>'
```

Comment: I get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: did you copy paste the code?? i have removed ". and ."

Comment: yes, I did copy paste. I paste it here: echo "thiscodeishere";